# What is the best way of regaining rep as an Unholy Traitor?

Tags: x3-terran-conflict

I recently loaded up an old file I had where I started out as an Unholy Traitor turned pirate and is now the scourge of the galaxy to every none pirate/Yaki/Teladi.  Now, I feel like doing some of the new missions introduced in the recent updates with my fully decked out Brigantine, but no race is offering me any worthy missions and I can't quite blow up xenon/khaak ships in those sectors without blowing up all their sector defence first since they hate me (I wonder why, haha).

Is there a sure fire way of regaining faction with all the races so I can do some of the storyline missions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to get an assassination mission against a pirate ship in your enemies' space. If your combat rank is high enough, you may get the chance to blow up several destroyers, which will give you a massive rep boost. Failing that, you can try for a patrol mission that takes you through enemy sectors, it should clear your reputation right up. Otherwise, hang around jumpgates to enemy sectors and see if you can ambush a pirate/Xenon formation as they leave the jumpgate. Argon will be happy if you kill Paranids in their space and vice versa, ditto for Boron/Split. You may be able to find missions from race X in a race Y sector, those could help you out too. Non-core secotrs have less strict security, so you may be able to fly there unmolested if you improve your reputation a bit.

Keep in mind that it's much easier to push reputation towards 0 (gain positive rep while your rep is negative and vice versa) and don't be discouraged.

If your turrets are too trigger-happy, you may set your ship's computer to recognize ships of race X as friendly and not consider hostile ships to be enemies.

Comment: Added assassination missions, probably the quickest way to regain rep.